# Quasidiagonal C*-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a nuclear $C^*$-algebra satisfying UCT condition. Then under what assumptions $A$ is quasidiagonal?

Comment: The most general theorem so far (as far as I know) is the celebrated Tikuisis-White-Winter theorem (see "Quasidiagonality of nuclear C*-algebras", Ann. Math. 2017, https://www.jstor.org/stable/24906439). It says that nuclear UCT algebras with faithful traces are quasi-diagonal. You can even change nuclearity with exactness when the trace is amenable, see "Quasi-diagonal traces on exact C*-algebras", J. Func. Anal. 272, by Jamie Gabe. Or the alternative proof by Chris Schafhauser in "A new proof of the Tikuisis-White-Winter theorem", J. Reine Angew Math 2017.

Comment: It should be remarked that all the former mentioned theorems actually prove that the involved traces are quasi-diagonal, not only the C*-algebras.

Comment: There are also quasidiagonal (QD) C*-algebras which have no traces (even some that are (non-simple) purely infinite). A beautiful theorem of Voiculescu states that homotopy of C*-algebras preserves QD, so the cone $C_0((0,1], A)$ is QD for *any* C*-algebra $A$ (as the cone is zero homotopic). In particular, any C*-subalgebra of such a cone is QD. In my paper [Traceless AF embeddings and unsuspended E-theory. Geom. Funct. Anal. 30 (2020), no. 2, 323–333] I show that exact C*-subalgebras of cones are characterised by their primitive ideal spaces having no non-empty compact open subsets.

Comment: But to answer the question more precisely, there is no characterisation of QD for nuclear UCT C*-algebras in general. If you added *simplicity* as an assumption, this is equivalent to being stably finite ($M_n(A)$ has no infinite projections for all $n\in \mathbb N$). This follows from theorems of Blackadar-Handelman and Haagerup (and Blackadar-Cuntz, Kirchberg in the stably projectionless case) to see that any simple exact C*-algebra has a non-trivial (possibly unbounded) trace, and then cut down to a hereditary C*-subalgebra and use the QD Theorem of Tikuisis-White-Winter.

Comment: @DiegoMartínez Do nuclearity and UCT imply quasidiagonality without any further assumption(like faithful traces)?

Comment: No, the Cuntz algebras $\mathcal O_n$ are nuclear, UCT but have infinite projections, hence they are not QD.

Comment: @JamieGabe Understood. How about UCT + Nuclearity + Simplicity?(according to your last comment)

Comment: Then QD is equivalent to being stably finite (as I wrote). Again, the Cuntz algebras are separable, simple, nuclear, unital, UCT, $\mathcal Z$-stable (and have many other nice properties) but they are not QD since they have infinite projections.

Comment: @JamieGabe So, we have two options eighter faithful traces or cone $C_0((0, 1], A)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128880/discussion-between-jamie-gabe-and-peg-leg-jonathan).